# Is it possible to create an Automated Touch/hold script using ADB shell?

Tags: input, touch, adb

I'm trying to set up an automated touch sequence using ADB for testing purposes, I've been searching for a few weeks now about information on how to create pauses, long touches, etc with no luck.
I know about using the following for taps and swipes:

```
input [touchscreen|touchpad] tap <x> <y>
input [touchscreen|touchpad] swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
```

But I'm not sure if they can be modified to create the things I mentioned earlier (pauses, long touches, holds).

What would a general script look like to create a sequence such as:

tap, tap, tap, tap, pause, long touch, pause, long touch, pause, tap, tap, tap, tap, pause, repeat

For example purposes assume all the commands are happening at the same `<x> <y>` locations.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using monkeyrunner, a tool that comes with the Android SDK.

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyView
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(timeout = 60, deviceId = "DEVICE_ID")
# DEVICE_ID is the device's serial number obtained by running adb devices

# to tap 4 times
for i in range(4):
    device.touch(x, y,MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

# to pause
MonkeyRunner.sleep(no_of_seconds)

# to long touch
device.touch(x, y,MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(no_of_seconds)
# to release the hold
device.touch(x, y,MonkeyDevice.UP)
```

Now, to include all these in a repeat cicle, you can use python while or for statements.

`monkeyrunner` is at `Android-sdk/tools/monkeyrunner`

Next run it `./monkeyrunner` you will enter interactive console of `Jython 2.5.3`

Or run saved script by `monkeyrunner ../Desktop/level.py`